# building storm-starter: getting error "POM for storm-core missing"

Tags: apache-storm

I've downloaded the incubator-storm code from https://github.com/apache/incubator-storm.  Now, I'm attempting to run **WordCountTopology** with the command:

```
mvn compile exec:java -Dstorm.topology=storm.starter.WordCountTopology
```

per instructions documented on https://github.com/apache/incubator-storm/tree/master/examples/storm-starter.  However, I am getting the following error:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-242-202-111:~/incubator-storm-master/examples/storm-starter$ mvn compile exec:java -Dstorm.topology=storm.starter.WordCountTopology
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.storm:storm-starter:jar:0.9.2-incubating-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'reporting.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.storm:storm:0.9.2-incubating-SNAPSHOT, /home/ubuntu/incubator-storm-master/pom.xml, line 661, column 21
[WARNING] 'reporting.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-report-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.storm:storm:0.9.2-incubating-SNAPSHOT, /home/ubuntu/incubator-storm-master/pom.xml, line 627, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building storm-starter 0.9.2-incubating-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.storm:storm-core:jar:0.9.2-incubating-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.156s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon May 05 02:56:08 UTC 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/56M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project storm-starter: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.storm:storm-starter:jar:0.9.2-incubating-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.apache.storm:storm-core:jar:0.9.2-incubating-SNAPSHOT in https://clojars.org/repo/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of clojars has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Any insight into what my issue might be is much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same problem, and found the answer from storm-user mailing list archives, refer to

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/storm-user/201404.mbox/%3C72091F29-8109-4A1C-A79D-DDD2D871737B%40petrolink.com%3E

Comment: After running commands noted in your link directly in the "incubator-storm-master" directory, then re-executing

"mvn compile exec:java -Dstorm.topology=storm.starter.WordCountTopology"

I got everything to build w/o error.  Thanks a bunch!!!